# How to escape metacharacters for egrep like metaquote from Perl?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl, quoting, escape-characters

Perl has a function called `metaquote()` to escape all special characters for a regular expression.

Is there an equivalent technique for `egrep`?

Example: If I am searching for the string `abc.def.ghi`, I need to remember to escape the dots manually, e.g., `abc\.def\.ghi`

I assume `egrep` does not have a built-in mode/feature to do this, but I am open to "one-liners" in Perl/sed/awk to simulate `metaquote()` for `egrep`.  Also, Perl's `metaquote()` might work in trivial cases, but the regular expression syntax is different between `egrep` and `perl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-F` options to make `grep` treat pattern as fixed string:

```
grep -F 'abc.def.ghi' <file
```

And also note that you don't need to invoke `egrep`.

Comment: Re: "you don't need to invoke `egrep`": As I understand, GNU egrep is little more than `grep -E` for extended regex.  I realise in my example above, the regex is trivial, but normally they are a bit more complex, so I use `egrep`.  Is `egrep` useless then?

Comment: @kevinarpe: `egrep` is the same as `grep -E`.

Comment: I want to clarify for this answer.  Option `-F` will not work with `egrep`; it only works with `grep`.  When I use `egrep -F`, I receive the error `egrep: egrep can only use the egrep pattern syntax`.

Comment: @kevinarpe: Yes, because using `-F` meaning you search for fixed-string, which is not consider a regex, so you have a conflict matcher. Try `grep -EF '123' <<<""` to see the error.

Answer (score 2):

You do have to do it yourself: this sed command escaped any non-alphanumeric character, which is what `quotemeta` does (IIRC)

```
str="abc.def.ghi"
escaped=$(sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\&/g' <<< "$str")

echo "$escaped"    # => abc\.def\.ghi
```

1. we expect this to match because it's using the original string as a regular expression

   ```
   $ echo "foo bar abc-def-ghi baz" | grep "$str"
   foo bar abc-def-ghi baz
   ```
2. we expect this not to match because it's using the escaped string.

   ```
   $ echo "foo bar abc-def-ghi baz" | grep "$escaped"
   $ echo $?
   1
   ```
3. we expect this to match because it's using the escaped string.

   ```
   $ echo "foo bar abc.def.ghi baz" | grep "$escaped"
   foo bar abc.def.ghi baz
   ```